# ISA Server for x64 systems? Or recommend other Firewall/Routing/VPN software

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, architecture, isa-server

we're a website that is going to have two servers behind the Firewall/Router Server (a web server and a database server). All three servers are going to be running **Windows Server 2008 R2** x64.

Excuse the crudity of my diagram (I know it's not even close to being technically correct, but it hopefully makes our topology a little clearer)...

[image: Diagram]

I'm currently configuring the server we want to use as a Firewall/Router/VPN, but to my great dismay it seems that **ISA Server 2006** (the software I thought would be a perfect fit) isn't compatible with x64 systems.

What should I do? Is there another Microsoft solution we can use (we have a BizSpark subscription)? Should I reinstall Windows Server 2008 as x86? Is there another piece of software that we should get instead? How does RRAS fit into this?

I can imagine this must be quite a common problem, and I'm really shocked that it's nearly 2010 and Microsoft haven't released a x64 compatible update...

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISA Server 2006 can only run on Windows Server 2003 x86, not even 2008 x86 would do.

If you want to run ISA, you should install Windows Server 2003 on the server you want to use as a firewall; otherwise, you'll have to go to the next-generation firewall solution from Microsoft: [ForeFront Threat Management Gateway 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/threat-management-gateway) (yes, "ISA Server" was a lot simpler to say and write).

Comment: Bah. Thanks for clearing that up, but FTMG is not yet part of the BizSpark subscription. I hope they're planning to add it soon :(

Comment: It has been released less than a week ago, give them a little time :-)

Comment: I just got an email from them saying they have "no plans" to release TMG to subscription. Damn.

Comment: After saying they had "no plans", forcing me down a long and painful RRAS route, they released it on BizSpark. Dargh. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my answer is RRAS. There's no other choice.